# R Tidytext unnest_tokens error when using a txt file as source

Tags: r, text-mining, tidytext

Very new to this topic. I am having trouble with the unnest_tokens function in the tidytext package. I have some texts stored in .txt format that I want to analyze.

An example would be putting the following sentences in a txt file then read it into R:

```
Emily Dickinson wrote some lovely text in her time.

text <- c("Because I could not stop for Death -",
          "He kindly stopped for me -",
          "The Carriage held but just Ourselves -",
          "and Immortality")
```

Below is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(readtext)
my_data <- read_file("exp.txt")
my_data_tibble <- tibble(text = my_data)
my_data_tibble %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, my_data)
```

Then I would get the error message below:

```
Error in check_input(x) : 
  Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.
```

Does anyone have a solution to my problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First input is the column name of output column that you want and second one is that of input.

```
library(tidytext)

my_data_tibble %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)

# A tibble: 20 x 1
#   word       
#   <chr>      
# 1 because    
# 2 i          
# 3 could      
# 4 not        
# 5 stop       
# 6 for        
# 7 death      
# 8 he         
#...
#....
```

Comment: much appreciated!